# How to do a length check using nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a length check on my dictionary as a form of simple validation. For example I'm trying to put a limit of number of players that can join a specific team which is a nested dictionary. Here's what I've done so far

```
teamS = {
"Team 1": {"Team Ahab":["Venom,Paz,Chico,Kaz,Miguel"],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Team 2": {"Team Ishmael":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Team 3": {"Team Miller":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Team 4": {"Team Raiden":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]}}


if len(teamS["Team 1"]["Team Ahab"]) > 5:
teamS["Team 1"]["Team Ahab"].pop(5)
print("This team is full so please join another one instead")
```

My ideal output would be like this

```
teamchoice = input("What team do you want to join) ("Team Ahab")
print("This team is full so please join another one)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is poor design.  You have two keys that make it harder for you to work.  If you want to key by team name, that's fine, but don't make a redundant team ID.  Just use a dictionary where the team is the key and the roster is a list of names, with built-in len.

```
teams = {
    "Ahab": {
        "roster": ["Venom", "Paz", "Chico", "Kaz", "Miguel"],
        "Score": [],
        "Event": []
    },
    "Ishmael" : {
        "roster:[],
        "Score": [],
        "Event": []
    },
    ...
}
```

Simply look up the given team; let's just call that `pref_team`.

```
if len(teamS[pref_team][roster]) >= 5:
    # reject membership
```

That should be enough to get you moving.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, to get the len of the team, you should do something like this:

```
print(len(str(teamS["Team 1"]["Team Ahab"]).split(",")))
```

You need to get the Dictionary inside the Team number, and then, the list of members is just an string separated by commas